# Creating something similar to Visual Studio Code's Interactive Playground

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I am wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to create an interactive editor like Visual Studio Code's Interactive Playground. The Interactive Playground can be accessed by the top toolbar: Help > Interactive Playground.

From my very limited knowledge of markdown files, I am assuming the interactive playground was built using something similar to a markdown file but the formatting of the code blocks and ability to edit them separate the Interactive Playground from typical markdown files. If anyone knows how to create something similar to the Interactive Playground, I would be very interested in finding out how it is done.

Comment: "I am wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to create an interactive editor like Visual Studio Code's Interactive Playground." Of course it is, since it has been done at least once already in Visual Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].